# ParsleyJS remote validator how to really validate it?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation, parsley.js

I'm having an issue which I'm dealing with for several hours and I can't figure it out how to access a value in php and return back to js.

This is my input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nr_ref" id="nr-ref"
     placeholder="Ref"
     data-parsley-group="step1"
     data-parsley-trigger="change"
     data-parsley-remote="validateit.php"
     data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp", "data": { "token": "value" } }'
     required>
```

My `validateit.php` is actually empty ;S

How to access the value of the input, so I can process it in my php file, and then return true / false displaying adequate message below the input element?

I'm loading both `parsley-remote.min.js` and `parsley.min.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Parsley in your above configuration would pass through `POST` method the variable `nr_ref` with the field value inside.

Basically, in your `validateit.php`, if you make

```
<?php
die(var_dump($_POST));
```

then you should see this variable and its value passed by parsley to your script (in `$_POST['nr_ref']`).

Feel free than to make your server-side checks and then return a 200 HTTP status code (with `header()`) if successful or 4xx either.

Hope that helped you.

Best